# ManyChat Bot not closing and 2 messenger chat appearing for new session

Tags: javascript, facebook-messenger-bot

Someone help, I have been trying to search for the code or styling that causes the issue of two chat widget appearing and X button won't work for new sessions, but I really couldn't find anything that cause this issue.
We installed this in our site www.besocialscene.com using  tag on many chat and we didn't add any  code.

Support told us that we need to remove other chat widget since there might be a possibility that there were some left-over code so we did ensure to remove it. But the issue keeps on occuring.

I wonder if this is caused by some JS Issue, when you reload our page the issue disappears but when cache is cleared and using new device the issue arises.

Comment: Are you using the https://botmakers.net/chatbot-templates/explore/manychat templates? If yes which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had a quick look at the manychat widget source on your page and this is what it says.

```
window.mcwidget = 
        {"appId":"532160876956612","pageId":"143687712333074",
         "widgets": [
                     {"widget_id":2530187,"page_id":"143687712333074",
                      "widget_type":"customer_chat",
                      "status":"active",
                      "name":"2018-Website-Widget-Social-Scene",
                      "data":{"setup":{"loggedInGreeting":""}},
                      "chat_ref":"w2530187"},

                     {"widget_id":2159609,"page_id":"143687712333074",
                     "widget_type":"customer_chat",
                     "status":"active","name":"Website Chat",
                     "data":{"setup":{"urlBlacklist":""}},
                     "chat_ref":"w2159609"},

                     {"widget_id":1940213,"page_id":"143687712333074",                         
                     "widget_type":"landing","status":"active",
                     "name":"Example Landing",
                     "data":[]}
                  ],
          "widgetLocale":"en_US","defaultSize":0,"fbSDKVersion":"v3.1"};
```

As you can see, there are **3 active widgets** linked to the same page. You probably want only one of them active and linked to your page. I think you need to recheck your configuration settings on your manychat account/dashboard, especially the part where you are connecting the widget to the page.

Comment: Hi, thanks @angela that could be one why two chat appeared reason, the chat button now can close but you need to click at least 6-10 times

Comment: How did you find it is it in the developer tools?

Comment: @Chrissa you still have two active widgets for the same page - not sure what your use case is. To check for your problem, I looked at your website page source , since you have not posted any code snippets. I also checked the general configuration of a ManyChat Bot. Thanks for accepting the answer.